# Using Python 2 and 3 but it cant find python 2 packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been using python 2.7.14 for awhile and have started using python 3.  I installed python 3.7.2  and the py launcher so I know how to switch versions using

```
py -2
py -3
```

When I run some of my python 2 files it cant find the modules, I get the the `No module named ___`

How can I get `py -2` to see my old modules location on my windows 7 computer.  Python is installed in C:\Python27.

Sample code

```
#! python2
from pytube import YouTube
```

Not sure if this helps but I have ArcGIS 10.6 installed. If I add check the sys.path my result is:

```
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.6\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.6\\ArcPy', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.6\\ArcToolBox\\Scripts']
```

The how did `sys.path` get changed?

Comment: try with ```pip3 install pytube```
you have to install the required module for version 3.7 also from pip

Answer (score 0):

Due to many incompatibilities, the Python community agreed to have the two versions use distinct paths.

It seems like the module for Python2 is missing or mislocated on your computer. Try running `pip install pytube` to fix this.

Comment: Try running 'pip install --ignore-installed pytube'. This will force pip to install the package even if it is already installed somewhere. If the package is still missing, try to set up a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/) for your script. This gets rid of most Python2/3 issues.